# background image cant b inserted

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

i want to insert image as bg in my program.I have added *andriod:background* but i didnt get image in design part

`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:andriod="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.madhu.c_indicator.MainActivity"
    andriod:background="@drawable/bg2">



</RelativeLayout>
```

when i run the program the following error appearing

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java" -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Didea.junit.sm_runner -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rindicatort.jar;C:\Users\MADHU\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\data\res;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-\app\build\intermediates\classes\test\debug;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-indicator\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug;C:\Users\MADHU\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\23.4.0\support-annotations-23.4.0.jar;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-indicator\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\23.4.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-indicator\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\23.4.0\res;C:\Users\MADHU\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-indicator\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\23.4.0\jars\libs\internal_impl-23.4.0.jar;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-indicator\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\23.4.0\res;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-indicator\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\23.4.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\MADHU\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-indicator\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-vector-drawable\23.4.0\res;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-indicator\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-vector-drawable\23.4.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-indicator\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.4.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-indicator\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.4.0\res;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-indicator\app\build\intermediates\sourceFolderJavaResources\test\debug;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-indicator\app\build\intermediates\sourceFolderJavaResources\debug;C:\Users\MADHU\AndroidStudioProjects\C-indicator\build\generated\mockable-android-23.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 @w@C:\Users\MADHU\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_junit0.tmp @C:\Users\MADHU\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_junit0.tmp -socket50943
0 test classes found in package 'drawable'

Process finished with exit code -1
Empty test suite.
```

plsss help me

Comment: Is your bg2 file in your project's ```/app/src/main/res/drawable/``` folder?

Comment: change andriod:background="@drawable/bg2" to android:background="@drawable/bg2"

Comment: i deleted this line i am getting **error parsing XML:unbound prefix** error

Comment: ya the file is in drawable folder @clark wilson

Comment: Oh, I found the problem. "android" is spelled wrong. in ```andriod:background="@drawable/bg2"```

Answer (score 1):

There is spelling error in line   andriod:background="@drawable/bg2"                 change 'andriod' to 'android'

Answer (score 0):

There is typo in your code, So

Change

```
andriod:background="@drawable/bg2"
```

from

```
android:background="@drawable/bg2"
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo on your code.
instead of  'andriod:background' use ''android:background'